# Better explanation of propagation of gravity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

There is a nice demostration picture concerning the propagation of gravity in finite time: http://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/teaching/HPS_0410/chapters/general_relativity_pathway/#Starting

[image]

It says:

> He (Einstein) examined gravitation theories, modified to allow for a finite time of propagation of effects, and found a result that aroused great suspicions in him. In the modified theories, the distance fallen by a body varies according to its sideways motion. In the simplest case, the body would fall a shorter distance if it has some sideways velocity.

However this explanation is vague and does not explain "why" the distance fallen by a body varies according to its sideways motion. Do they mean relativistic speeds or just any speeds? Why this happens?

Comment: This doesn't happen, in reality. It apparently happened in some of the predecessors to general relativity that added a Lorentz-covariant propagational delay to Newtonian gravity. This is perhaps a better question for the History of Science and Mathematics stackexchange site, http://hsm.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Does that not describe a modified theory of gravity which resulted from Einstein's work on formulating general relativity? For most observations, components are independent, and I believe the article said the noticed effects in the diagram were deemed negligible. As a tool in developing general relativity, it seems like this modified gravity was set aside in favor of his argument on accelerating reference frames.